# How to make sql query case insensitive in sqlite for my iOS app

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I am doing a sql query in my sqlite database like this:

```
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM PROFILE WHERE no = '%@'", txtNo.text];
```

But I need the query to be case insensitive. How do I do that?

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: Like rmaddy said, use `upper` function on both the input and the column, or use the `LIKE` operator rather than `=` (though, if using `LIKE` you have to be careful about wildcard character, `%` in the input string).

Comment: In addition to rmaddy's observation about SQL injection attacks, a more practical problem would be if `txtNo` had a value like "Joe's Bar & Grill", where the apostrophe would be interpreted as the closing quote to the `WHERE` clause. `sqlite3_bind_text` is definitely the way to go. Or libraries like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) give you methods like `executeQuery` where they take parameters like `stringWithFormat`, and take care of the gory details of `sqlite3_bind_text` behind the scenes for you (but you still use the `?` placeholders).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `upper()` function:

```
SELECT * FROM PROFILE WHERE upper(no) = upper(?);
```

You should never use `stringWithFormat` to create your queries. Make proper use of `sqlite3_bind_xxx` to bind a value to the query. The reason for this is that making proper use of `sqlite3_bind_xxx` will ensure the value is properly quoted and any special characters are properly escaped. Read up on sQL injection hacks for the importance of proper escaping.

Comment: +1 for both use of `upper` as well as the counsel to not use `stringWithFormat`!